# js tree is not working in ie when handle check/uncheck event and set all check box true together

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, jstree-dnd

I am using jstree to bind data. I have checked (select) all checkbox and also call check/uncheck event of checkbox. it is working fine in Chrome but in IE i can handle check/uncheck event but it is not checked (select) all checkbox by default.

Please find below code :

```
$('#filterResult').jstree({
        "core": {
            "data": data,
            "themes": {
                "icons": false
            },
            check_callback: false
        },
        'checkbox': {
            three_state: true,
            cascade: 'none',
            whole_node: false, 
            tie_selection: false, // when remove this then all checkbox are selected by dafualt but check/uncheck event is not working
            real_checkboxes: true
        },
        "plugins": [
            "wholerow",
            "checkbox"
        ]
    })
        .on('loaded.jstree', function () {
            $("#filterResult").jstree().check_all(true);
           // $("#filterResult").jstree("select_all");               
        })
        .on("check_node.jstree uncheck_node.jstree", function (e, data) {

          console.log(data.node.id);
            }
        });
```

When I remove  tie_selection: false from 'checkbox' then selected all checkbox in IE is working but fine but then checkbox check/uncheck event is not working.

Above code is working in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the *`loaded.jstree`* event does not get triggered on IE (try setting break points, does not work).

For that you can try replacing it with *`ready.jstree`*

Here is [pen](https://codepen.io/coding_vk_ventures/pen/BaBWaaa) of the code.

Hope it helps !